# Does HBase need mapreduce or yarn?

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, hadoop-yarn

Does HBase need mapreduce/yarn, or it only need hdfs?
For a basic usage of HBase, like create table, insert data, scan/get data, I don't see any reason to use mapreduce/yarn.
Please help me out with this, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right . HBase needs only HDFS for columnar store , it doesn't need mapreduce/yarn.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to paralellice, you don't need YARN, only HDFS, but if you use a bulk, YARN is necesary